# Скрипт автоматической публикации .nupkg в пост сборке

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget

Поднял свой Nuget Server.
Теперь хочу при сборке проекта в VS17 автоматически генерить файл .nupkg и также автоматически отправлять на свой Nuget Server. С генерацией особо вопросов не возникло, а вот с публикацией затык. В сети предлагают в BuildIvents post build прописать скрипт, который будет автоматически заниматься публикацией.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос в том что я не имею понятия как это сделать. Может знает кто как это сделать или може другой способ.
Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Таки билд и деплой - это разные вещи, зачем вам понадобилось объединять их в одно?

Comment: @tym32167 (возможно я не правильно сформулировал) я до этого делал все с помощью GUI nuget.exe, и это забирает время, на днях узнал что это все можно автоматизировать, нажатием лишь кнопки build в VS17

Comment: Я про то, что, я, например, могу билдить проект каждые 10 минут, особенно когда тесты пишу. В вашем сценарии я бы на каждый билд выкладывал новую версию в нугет. Это точно то, что вам надо?

Comment: @tym32167 Да это то что мне нужно. Мне главное разобраться в самом принципе написания таких команд.

Comment: @UserName не подскажите как или может направите куда нужно?

Comment: @РоманТимохов, очень сумбурно, так что в случае чего спрашивайте. Расширю или поправлю ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно ознакомится с тем, что такое [MSBuild Targets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2017).

Если упрощенно, то `targets` - функции описываемые посредством `xml`. Можно управлять последовательностю запуска каждого из них. В простейшем случае мы имеем последовательность: `Build` -> ... -> `Pack` -> `Publish`.

---

Если тип проекта не `.NET SDK` то, потребуется установить пакет [NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/5.0.0-preview2.5782) содержащий все необходимое для операции упаковки, в ином случае все свойства и `targets` будут импортированы автоматически.

Для того, чтобы пакет собирался необходимо определить свойство `GeneratePackageOnBuild`:

```
/p:GeneratePackageOnBuild="true"
```

В зависимости от условия выше может понадобится определения дополнительных свойств, перечень которых находится [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target). За саму генерацию пакетов отвечает `pack` target.

---

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="Publish" AfterTargets="Build">

    <Message Text="----------Entry----------" Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="         Publish         " Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="----------Entry----------" Importance="high"/>

    <Exec Command="dotnet nuget push $(PackageOutputPath)\*.nupkg -k $(DevelopNuGetApiKey) -s $(DevelopNuGetSource)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Команда `dotnet nuget push` инициирует отправку пакетов, которые находятся в заданной директории - `$(PackageOutputPath)`.

Переменные `$(DevelopNuGetApiKey)` и `$(DevelopNuGetSource)` можно задать в том же файле, в данном случае они берутся из окружения - метод обращения к тем и другим будет одинаков.

---

[dotnet nuget push](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-push?tabs=netcore2x) | [Target-Maps](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/wiki/Target-Maps.md).